# is there well defined next_batch function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

While writing code using neural network, we normally use next_batch function like below :

```
mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

In case of using other methods such as random forest, svm, baysian network,
we don't have to use above code, because all training data are put in it at once.
But if we want to use neural network for the data, we have to make code next_batch. Of course I knew tensorflow's next_batch function code, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c36309c37b04843030664cdc64aca2bb7d6ecaa/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160),
But if the data are as much as hard to load on memory, above method would be improper.
is there well defined next_batch function possible for huge dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you found my answer useful,please upvote or accept it

Comment: sure, it does, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For huge datasets that can't fit in memory, you can use TensorFlow's built-in support for distributed training.

See, the [reading data](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) chapter in the TF programmer's guide. Specifically, read the **Batching** section.
There's also a great [blog post](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/), about RNNs, where the first part gives short and concise examples of how to use TF support for distributed training.